How to calculate the full second-order correction to the eigenvalues in degenerate perturbation theory?
I am approaching degenerate perturbation theory from the point of view of continuum mechanics.
Consider the eigensystem:
$$C = \sum_{k=1}^{3}\lambda_{k}N_{k}N_{k}^{T}$$
where:

$C$ is a real symmetric invertible positive definite tensor of rank 3.
$\lambda_{k}$ are the eigenvalues of $C$.
$N_{k}$ are the eigenvectors of the same tensor $C$.

I have a strain energy density given by:
$$W = \sum_{k=1}^{3} \lambda^{u}_{k} - 3$$
where:

$u$ is a non-zero material parameter.

I need to calculate $S_{ij}$ and $M_{ijkl}$ defined as follows:
$$S_{ij} = 2\frac{\partial W}{\partial C_{ij}}$$
which evaluates to:
$$S_{ij} = 2\sum_{k=1}^{3} u\lambda_{k}^{u-1}\frac{\partial \lambda_{k}}{\partial C_{ij}}$$
Using degenerate perturbation theory I am able to calculate:
$$\frac{\partial \lambda_{k}}{\partial C_{ij}} = (N_{k})_{i}\otimes (N_{k})_{j}$$
where:

$\otimes$ denotes the tensor product.
$(N_{k})_{i}$ is the corrected basis in case of degeneracy.

The fourth order tensor $M_{ijkl}$ is further defined as follows:
$$M_{ijkl} = 4\frac{\partial^{2} W}{\partial C_{kl} \partial C_{ij}}$$
which evaluates to:
$$M_{ijkl} = 4\sum_{m=1}^{3}\left( u(u-1)\frac{\partial \lambda_{m}}{\partial C_{kl}} \frac{\partial \lambda_{m}}{\partial C_{ij}} + u\lambda_{m}^{u-1}\frac{\partial^{2} \lambda_{m}}{\partial C_{kl} \partial C_{ij}}\right)$$
I am able to calculate the first term. However for the second term, all resources I looked at, only calculate the non-degenerate subspace component contribution to the second derivative given by:
$$\frac{\partial^{2} \lambda_{m,z}}{\partial C_{kl} \partial C_{ij}}|_{\widehat{V}} = \sum_{p}\frac{(N_{m,z})_{k}\otimes (N_{p})_{l}\otimes (N_{m,z})_{i}\otimes (N_{p})_{j}}{\lambda_{p} - \lambda_{m}}$$
where:

$p\in$ non-degenerate space eigenvalues.
$m\in$ degenerate space eigenvalue.
$(m,z)\in$ denotes the $z^{th}$ state among the $m$ degenerate states.
$\widehat{V}$ denotes the component of the non-degenerate subspace to any equation.
$V_{N}$ denotes the component of the degenerate subspace to any equation.

They do not calculate the degenerate subspace component contribution to the second derivative of the eigenvalues.
$\textbf{How can I calculate the contribution of the degenerate subspace }$$V_{N}$$\textbf{ (given by }$$\frac{\partial^{2} \lambda_{m,z}}{\partial C_{kl} \partial C_{ij}}|_{V_{N}}$$\textbf{)}$$\\$ $\textbf{to the second derivative of the eigenvalues?}$
